# Can't get Android device to be a target for Worklight application deployment

Tags: javascript, android, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a Motorola DroidX that I want to use for testing my Javascript app that runs under Worklight. The DroidX is running Android 2.3.4. My Worklight project is configured for Android-8 (Android 2.2). I followed the tutorials for downloading the Goggle USB driver and including it in the Windows 7 device driver search. I also downloaded and installed the most recent Motorola USB drivers.   I think I now have the right drivers in place to handle the USB for the DroidX.
I changed my DroidX settings to include USB debugging, and I've tried connecting to Worklight with both PC Mode and MASS Storage.  I've issued the ADB devices command, and it shows that an Android device is connected to the PC.   However, I never get any deployment dialog for the DroidX when I do the Build All and Deploy...
It seems like I'm missing some subtle item that is preventing the DroidX from being considered as a target for the Javascript application deployment.

How do I go about debugging - what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Did you add an Android environment to your app?

After hitting "Build All and Deploy", are you going to the Android native project (it should be a folder below your WL project) and right-click "Run As > Android Application"?

After you do all that, do you get an errors/warnings in the console or in LogCat?

Can you see LogCat?

Finally, to make sure this is a WL issue, can you please create a Native HelloWorld Android app, and see if you can deploy that into your Droid X from your Eclipse environment. You may have an issue that has nothing to do with WL.

Comment: Yes, I have an Android environment added. I also do the Run As> Android Application. When I do that, it launches the Android emulator. I don't see anything in LogCat that isn't related to the Android emulator starting up.  I'll look into attempting a native hello world app.